# Why might "Philosophiae Doctor" (the source of "Ph.D.") have been preferred over "Doctor Philosophiae"?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, academic-latin, word-order

The English abbreviation [*Ph.D.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy) comes from the Latin for *Doctor of Philosophy*, which I understand would be either *Philosophiae Doctor* or *Doctor Philosophiae*.

I know word order is flexible in Latin, but I thought that the general rule was "noun + modifier."  If so, *Doctor Philosophiae* would be the preferred form.  And yet the widespread usage of *Ph.D.* suggests that the opposite order, *Philosophiae Doctor*, prevailed.  Is there a grammatical reason that the latter option became the source of the *Ph.D.* abbreviation?

Related question on ELU.SE: [Why PhD, and not DPh](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/278027/53711)

Comment: I was always under the impression that it was Philosophical Doctor, not Doctor of Philosophy (which, though it makes little sense in English, might be fine in Latin)

Comment: In the German-speaking countries, the usual form is _Dr. phil._ (and _Dr. med._, _Dr. iur._ etc.).

Comment: Isn't this question about English rather than Latin? As far as I know, Ph.D. is an English phrase, not a Latin phrase. It's based on Latin words, but these words were assembled to fit English speakers, not by Latin speakers.

Comment: @Gilles I see it as a Latin word order question that later has an impact on English.  Why does "Philosophiae Doctor" exist in the first place?  There's nothing "more English" about Ph.D. than D.Ph. or D.P., so where did it come from?

Comment: @Nathaniel I'll keep looking for the exact dates these came into being. Also, note that in Oxford and other places, M.Phil. and D.Phil. are standard, not unlike the German abbreviation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no significance to the word order, and both are perfectly acceptable in Latin. In fact, it is only in English translation that there is a difference felt. The genitive in Latin is perfectly at home come before or after the noun. For example, Lucretius wrote *De Rerum Natura* while Cicero wrote *De Natura Deorum*. The choice is stylistic.

And Ph.D. isn't so standard after all. While it's the most popular abbreviation in the American system, in the UK you can get a D.Phil. in [Oxford](https://www.ox.ac.uk/admissions/graduate/courses/dphil-philosophy), and in [Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy#Germany) the abbreviation begins with Dr.

So there's no grammatical reason for adopting one or the other.

Answer (score -1):

"Philosophiae" is not a modifier, but a noun in the genitive case, so the assumption behind the question is faulty.

Comment: It is indeed a genitive noun, but it's also acting as a modifier (modifying _doctor_).